# GameCenter GKMatchmakerViewController auto-match not working, expectedPlayerCount always 1, solutions?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, multiplayer

I cannot establish a connection between two players using auto-match and GKMatchmakerViewController.

The behavior is this:

1. didFindMatch is called
2. expectedPlayerCount is not zero (always 1)
3. didChangeState is never called
4. after an extended period of time the player disconnected is received.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the correct number of players connected, make sure you setup your `GKMatchRequest` properly.

In this example, I have a game that only works if there are two players connected, so I set the min & max players count to 2:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;

GKMatchmakerViewController* mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
```

Then, everything you noted works as expected.

---

**EDIT:**

After reading your question again, also make sure you have retained the `GKMatch` object given to you by:

`-(void) matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController*)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch*)match;`

And of course, you have to set the delegate of this match object:

```
//Done!
-(void) matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController*)viewController didFindMatch:(GKMatch*)match{
    [self dismissModalViewController];
    [self setCurrentMatch:match];

    match.delegate  = self;

    if (!matchStarted && match.expectedPlayerCount == 0){
        matchStarted = YES;
        [delegate onMatchStart];
        self.handlerVoice = [OnlineHandlerVoice handlerWithMatch:currentMatch];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. However, everything is done as you said already and I get this behavior. Other ideas?

Comment: If you did all the above, and you are 100% sure, do the usual: 1- delete the app, 2- sign out of game center, 3- clean your build folder, 4- reboot the device, 5- create a new sandbox account using the AlertView inside the app, 6- cross your fingers. **NOTE:** Never test it on iOS simulator.

Comment: So if I have only one device, I cannot test it between simulator and device? If that is the case it really sucks.

Comment: Yup, sucks so bad .. I believe I even read it in the documentation that Simulator won't operate properly using matchmaking. However, I believe I was lucky and it worked a few times.

Comment: I was thinking on going to a starbucks and changing the network, maybe that could help. But if that is not the case I'm stuck since I don't have 2 devices. Isn't at least auto-matching suppose to work in the simulator? I knew that one should work...Anyway, thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: I've been able to use automatching successfully between device and simulator.  Invites do not work however, presumably because there's no way to send a push notification to the simulator.